E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:961] remapper failed
I have saved my trained Keras model as a PB file using Python 3.12.5 and TensorFlow 2.17.0.
The model is to be deployed for inference in my C++ software. For this, I am using the TensorFlow for C library 2.15.0 as a DLL for Windows. When I load the PB model, I get the following error:
2024-09-01 16:09:38.024565: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:961] remapper failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Mutation::Apply error: fanout 'generator/tf.concat_6/concat' exist for missing node 'generator/conv2d/BiasAdd'.

Is this anything to worry about? Am I experiencing any performance hit as a result? If yes, can anyone advise/hints how I might fix it, please?
I found a similar question asked here but with no responses (and I don't have sufficient reputation to comment on that thread either).
I did not get the error when using TensorFlow for C version 2.13.0. So one solution would be to revert to this older library, but I feel I should be using up-to-date versions libraries where possible. There must be a better way...?
Inference seems to be working correctly, despite the error, which I think makes sense since this seems to be about the grappler optimizer.

Could you please provide  the relevant code snippet for the generator/conv2d layer and its subsequent layers, including the BiasAdd layer? This will make it easier to identify and fix the problem
